# Missing file during npm package install related to staging directory causes install to fail?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, enoent

I am tring to install the *readdir-enhanced* package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/readdir-enhanced

When I run this command:

```
npm install readdir-enhanced --save-dev
```

I get the following error dump, which is identical to what is found in the NPM install logs (*Note, the first 585 lines are not shown because the file is huge and those lines contain the full "silly" tree*):

```
$ npm install readdir-enhanced --save
...
586 warn basil@1.0.0 No description
587 warn basil@1.0.0 No repository field.
588 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
589 warn enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename './zeppelin-os-work/basil/node_modules/.staging/fsevents-f5a9ea9f/node_modules/abbrev' -> './zeppelin-os-work/basil/node_modules/.staging/abbrev-0837c875'
590 verbose enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
590 verbose enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
591 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename './zeppelin-os-work/basil/node_modules/.staging/zos-0b4473df/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced' -> './zeppelin-os-work/basil/node_modules/.staging/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced-51fb6215'
592 verbose cwd ./zeppelin-os-work/basil
593 verbose Linux 4.15.0-22-generic
594 verbose argv "./.nvm/versions/node/v10.2.1/bin/node" "./.nvm/versions/node/v10.2.1/bin/npm" "install" "readdir-enhanced" "--save"
595 verbose node v10.2.1
596 verbose npm  v6.1.0
597 error path ./zeppelin-os-work/basil/node_modules/.staging/zos-0b4473df/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced
598 error code ENOENT
599 error errno -2
600 error syscall rename
601 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename './zeppelin-os-work/basil/node_modules/.staging/zos-0b4473df/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced' -> './zeppelin-os-work/basil/node_modules/.staging/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced-51fb6215'
602 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
603 verbose exit [ -2, true ]
```

What is this **.staging** directory and how can I fix this problem?

Relevant versions:

- Ubuntu: 18.04, Bionic Beaver
- Node.JS: v10.2.1
- NPM: 6.1.0